# replacing for loops in a function with vector calculations to speed up R

Tags: r

Say I have some data in data frame `d1`, that describes how frequently different sample individuals eat different foods, and a final column describing whether or not those foods are cool to eat. The data are structured like this.

```
OTU.ID<- c('pizza','taco','pizza.taco','dirt')
s1<-c(5,20,14,70)
s2<-c(99,2,29,5)
s3<-c(44,44,33,22)
cool<-c(1,1,1,0)

d1<-data.frame(OTU.ID,s1,s2,s3,cool)
print(d1)
      OTU.ID s1 s2 s3 cool
1      pizza  5 99 44    1
2       taco 20  2 44    1
3 pizza.taco 14 29 33    1
4       dirt 70  5 22    0
```

I have written a function that, for each sample, `s1:s3`, the number of cool foods that were consumed, and the total number of foods that were consumed. It runs as a for loop on each line of the data table (which is extremely slow).

```
cool.food.abundance<- function(food.table){
samps<-colnames(food.table)
#remove column names that are not sample names
samps<-samps[!samps %in% c("OTU.ID","cool")]

#create output vectors for for loop
    id<-c()
    cool.foods<-c()
    all.foods<-c()
    #run a loop that stores output ids and results as vectors
    for(i in 1:length(samps)){
        x<- samps[i]
        y1<-sum(food.table[samps[i]]*food.table$cool)
        y2<-sum(food.table[samps[i]])
        id<-c(id,x)
        cool.foods<-c(cool.foods,y1)
        all.foods<-c(all.foods,y2)
    }
    #save results as a data frame and return the data frame object
    results<-data.frame(id,cool.foods,all.foods)
    return(results)
}
```

So, if you run this function, you will get a new table of sample IDs, the number of cool foods that sample ate, and the total number of foods that sample ate.

```
cool.food.abundance(d1)
  id cool.foods all.foods
1 s1         39       109
2 s2        130       135
3 s3        121       143
```

How can I replace this for-loop with vector calculations to speed this up? I would really like to be able for the function to operate on dataframes loaded with the `fread` function in the `data.table` package.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try

```
library(data.table)#v1.9.5+
dcast(melt(setDT(d1), id.var=c('OTU.ID', 'cool'))[,
         sum(value) ,.(cool, variable)], variable~c('notcool.foods',
       'cool.foods')[cool+1L], value.var='V1')[,
    all.foods:= cool.foods+notcool.foods][, notcool.foods:=NULL]
#      variable cool.foods all.foods
#1:       s1         39       109
#2:       s2        130       135
#3:       s3        121       143
```

Or instead of using `dcast` we can summarise the result (as in @jeremycg's post) as there are only two groups

```
 melt(setDT(d1), id.var=c('OTU.ID', 'cool'), variable.name='id')[,
     list(all.foods=sum(value), cool.foods=sum(value[cool==1])) , id]
 #   id all.foods cool.foods
 #1: s1       109         39
 #2: s2       135        130
 #3: s3       143        121
```

Or you can use `base R`

```
nm1 <- paste0('s', 1:3)
res <- t(addmargins(rowsum(as.matrix(d1[nm1]), group=d1$cool),1)[-1,])

colnames(res) <- c('cool.foods', 'all.foods')
res
 #   cool.foods all.foods
 #s1         39       109
 #s2        130       135
 #s3        121       143
```

Comment: I get the following error: "Error: could not find function "dcast"."

Comment: @colin I am using the devel version of `data.table` Otherwise, you can load `library(reshape2)` and get the `dcast`

Comment: ah yes- the newest version of data table. Is there a way without using the newest version that isn't available using the package installer? I am hoping to share this script with other users who probably don't know how or want to install packages beyond the R interface.

Comment: @colin You can install `library(reshape2)` which also have `dcast` function.  In this particular case, that also should work

Comment: got reshape2 loaded. Its throwing this error now: Error in parse(text = x) : <text>:2:0: unexpected end of input
1: c("notcool.foods", "cool.foods")[cool
   ^

Comment: @colin That was just to rename the columns.  May be you can take that out, `variable~cool, value.var='V1'`

Comment: the base R solution is perfect. I've been messing around with it, trying to get it to label the first column as "id" rather than a #. Any tips?

Comment: @colin The output is a matrix with rownames.  We can create a data.frame out of it. `d2 <- data.frame(id=row.names(res), res); rownames(d2) <- NULL`

Answer (score 3):

Here's how I would do it, with `reshape2` and `dplyr`:

```
library(reshape2)
library(dplyr)
d1 <- melt(d1, id = c("OTU.ID", "cool"))
d1 %>% group_by(variable) %>% 
       summarise(all.foods = sum(value), cool.foods = sum(value[cool == 1]))
```

Comment: May be you can also place all the steps within the chain and  with `gather`.